# Using python to talk to a terminal program back/forth

Tags: python, linux, terminal, subprocess

So I've been using subprocess and pexpect 
to try to interact with a separate program running in the terminal. I need to feed it a command, with arguments, and be able to receive it's response and potentially send it more commands.

With subprocess, I have only been able to launch a terminal, but not feed it commands. Or I can pass ONE line of command to an emulated terminal within python. The issue it that it's one-and-done and I can't really interact with it.

pexpect seems to only be able to initiate one command, and then respond to the terminal in an automated fashion, I couldn't find relevant and up to date documentation that went over what I needed.

Are there better modules to use for this? Or am I using them the wrong way?
-Thanks,
-Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pexpect is your best candidate, as far as I'm aware.

It's [documentation](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) matches version on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/) - 3.2 as for now.

If you would like to run bunch of commands one after another you can try to divide commands with ";" or "&", depends on your usage.

Btw. please take a look at [example section](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html).